# Angular 6 response 'string' from web api controller

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core

When I am making request to Web Api Controller

```
this.http.get("https://localhost:44354/api/home/5",{responseType: 'text' })
  .subscribe(result => { console.log(result); });
```

in console `result` I get

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input↵
>   at AppComponent.push../src/app/app.component.ts.AppComponent.setTitle (http://localhost:4200/main.js:137:14)↵
>   at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.ngfactory.js:13:27)↵
>   at handleEvent (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:67178:41)↵
>   at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:68272:25)↵
>   at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:67975:12)↵
>   at dispatchEvent (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:64627:25)↵
>   at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:65074:38↵
>   at HTMLButtonElement. (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:74051:36)↵
>   at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2766:31)↵
>   at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:61652:33)

How to force Angular 6 recognize string?

**Startup.cs**

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin().AllowCredentials());
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  responsText: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  setTitle(): void {
    this.http.get("https://localhost:44354/api/home/5",{responseType: 'text' })
      .subscribe(result => { console.log(result); });
    debugger;
  }
}
```

**HomeController**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET api/<controller>/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
}
```

Comment: I think no need of this:`{responseType: 'text' }`

Comment: Why dont you created service to fetch the data from API its not good practice to call API in component itself!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale, it is tutorial for me.

Comment: What do you get if you put that URL in the browser?

Comment: @Crowcoder, I get blank screen with text "value".

Comment: Where did you called `this.setTitle();` function

Comment: @PrashantPimpale If you read the StackTrace, you will see it's from a button

Comment: Check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50798592/angular-6-how-to-set-response-type-as-text-while-making-http-call

Comment: As a sanity check, see if you can get a controller action that returns JSON to work.

Comment: could you get the right response by other way, like `postman`?

Comment: you have used `https` in API call from angular, try changing to `http`.

Comment: are you able to log the result?

Comment: I tried you code and it works well.I do not see the `AppComponent.push` function which may cause this problem.Could you post that?