# Error message in Angular 6 with Spring Response Entity

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I have a web application with Springboot and Angular 6.

A response entity with a detailed error message does not show the right error in Angular (instead of "Invalid Excel file" displays "Http failure response for 
           http://localhost:8081/api/v1/activities/excel/import: 500 OK")

Controller's code:

```
...
@PostMapping("/activities/excel/import")
public ResponseEntity<?> import(...) {
    return new ResponseEntity<> ("Invalid Excel file", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
...
```

UI (Angular 6):

```
importFromExcel() {
    this.activityService.importFromExcel(this.file).subscribe(
        (result) => {...},
        (error) => {
            console.log (error.error) //displays undefined
            console.log (error.name) //displays undefined
            console.log (error.message) //displays  undefined
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error)) //displays Http failure response for http://localhost:8081/api/v1/activities/excel/import: 500 OK 
        }
    )
}
```

How can I retrieve the HTTP response body?

PROBLEM SOLVED 
An interceptor (which have been added in other parts of the code) was handling error messages from backend in an incomplete way. As a result in some places in the app (like my example) the error messages were no longer displayed. Problem identified :).

Comment: Please, add the output of `JSON.stringify(error)` and `typeof error` to the question

Comment: @Vusal : Thank you for your help. The result on the JSON(stringify(error)) was "Http failure response for http://localhost:8081/api/v1/activities/excel/import: 500 OK" - see the description.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve an http response body in the next way:

```
this.activityService.importFromExcel(this.file).subscribe(
  data => console.log('success', data),
  error => console.log('oops', error.error)
);
```

The `error.error` should contain the HTTP response body.

Please check the next links for more information:

1. [Catching errors in Angular HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46019771/catching-errors-in-angular-httpclient)
2. [Angular 6: How to set response type as text while making http call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50798592/angular-6-how-to-set-response-type-as-text-while-making-http-call)
3. [HttpErrorResponse#error is not instance of Error in client-side/network error](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18690)

Comment: My problem is that the error.error displays "undefined" and not the body set in the Controller.