# Typescript http.get Error: No overload matches this call

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to get a text file from the server so I have done this:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Accept': 'text/html',
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'
  }),
  responseType: 'text'
};
this.http.get<any>(url, httpOptions).subscribe(response => {
  const blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'text/csv' });
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const anchor = document.createElement('a');
  anchor.download = 'user-permission-auditlog' + endDate.toUTCString() + '.csv';
  anchor.href = url;
  anchor.click();
});
```

And it works exactly the way I want it to. However the compiler cries out in pain:

error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
      Overload 1 of 15, '(url: string, options: { headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe: "events"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }): Observable<...>', gave the following error.
        Argument of type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; responseType: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe: "events"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }'.
          Property 'observe' is missing in type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; responseType: string; }' but required in type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe: "events"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }'.

It lists 3 of the 15, all of them complaining that responseType should be 'json' but 'text' as a responseType is definitely one of the overloads:

`get(url: string, options: { headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType: "text"; withCredentials?: boolean; }): Observable<string>`

https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 15):

You have to cast httpOptions to Object. I had the same problem and it worked perfectly for me.

```
 const httpOptions : Object = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Accept': 'text/html',
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'
  }),
  responseType: 'text'
};
```

Comment: casting, yeah baby! this is the one! Thank you.

Comment: This is the right solution for Angular 13

Comment: casting works. Can anyone explain why I had to cast the options in order to make it work?

Answer (score 8):

According [GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18672#issuecomment-455435341) it should be fixed with:

> The version of get that accepts responseType:'text' is not generic, since you're already stating the response would be a string.

So instead of:

```js
return this.http.get<string>(this.url, {responseType: 'text'});
```

Just use the non-generic one:

```js
return this.http.get(this.url, {responseType: 'text'});
```

And see SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50798592/angular-6-how-to-set-response-type-as-text-while-making-http-call).

Comment: This should be the selected answer!

Answer (score 7):

Okay so the fix was to change the responseType to `'text' as 'json'`, then replace the return type of `any` to `string` (which is how it is determining which overload to use).

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Accept': 'text/html',
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'
  }),
  responseType: 'text' as 'json'
};
this.http.get<string>(url, httpOptions).subscribe(response => {
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add **type** to httpOptions

Eg: const httpOptions:**any** = {
headers: new HttpHeaders({
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}),
'observe': 'response'
};

Addtional tip: Adding 'observe': 'response' will observe the whole response which helps us to fetch response.status (i.e. status code)