# How to let Angular interceptor know that certain request's response type is text instead of json?

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6

I have the following interceptor code which works fine when response type is json. However, for certain requests, I get response type text if successful, yet the interceptor interpret it as error. How do I conditionally let the interceptor know the response type?

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>{

if (authService.getToken()) {
  request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', authService.getToken()) });
}
if (!request.headers.has('Content-Type')) {
  request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json') });
}
request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json') });
return next.handle(request).pipe(
  map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
    if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
      console.log('event--->>>', event);
    }
    return event;
  }),
  catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      let data = {};
      data = {
          reason: error && error.error && error.error.reason ? error.error.reason : '',
          status: error.status
      };
      console.log(data);
      return throwError(error);
  })
);
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 6: How to set response type as text while making http call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50798592/angular-6-how-to-set-response-type-as-text-while-making-http-call)

Comment: @TheHeadRush I have came across that as well. I'd just like to know if this is something that can be done within the interceptor code.

Comment: Interceptors examine every request. If you really want all that overhead for something that could be as easily accomplished in the service catch the outbound requests to the endpoint(s) that return a text response and add the header configuration shown in the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks @TheHeadRush for the explanation, you are right.