# Spanish character is imported wrongly

Tags: angular, typescript, encoding, filereader

Error: **Spanish character is imported wrongly.**

The text file contains Spanish and English characters.

*.txt

```
Jose Nuñez,David Gutiérrez,Rocío Moreno,César Millones .....
```

Output after import to the server

```
Jose NuÃ±ez,David GutiÃ©rrez,RocÃ­o Moreno ....
```

*.ts

```
onFileChange(event: any) {
    const target: DataTransfer = <DataTransfer>(event.target);
    if (target.files.length !== 1) throw new Error('Cannot use multiple files');
    if (target.files.length !== 1 && event.target.accept !== ".txt") throw new Error('Cannot use multiple files');
    this.uploadedFileName = target.files[0].name;
    if (target.files.length == 1 && (target.files[0].type == ".txt" || target.files[0].type == "text/plain")) {
      this.uploadedFileName = event.target.files[0].name;
      if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
        const file = event.target.files[0];
        this.tFileList = event.target.files[0];
        this.searchFilterForm.get('edt').setValue(file);
      }
    }
    else {
      this.processErrorDetails = "Please select .txt file only!";
    }

  }
```

Service

```
public Import(body: any, observe: any = 'body', reportProgress: boolean = false): Observable < any > {
    let headers = this.defaultHeaders;

    headers.append('Content-Type', 'text/plain');

    return this.httpClient.post<any>(`${this.URL}/import_files`,
        body,
        {
            observe: 'response'
            , headers: headers

        }
    );

}
```

Comment: This is an encoding problem: you have two incompatible encodings. it seems the first is Latin1, and the second it is UTF-8 (very recommended for web, and all things, fonts now uses Unicode (UTF-8 or UTF-16) -- check with your text viewer/editor which encoding you are using, and maybe you can use it to convert to UTF-8)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 6: How to set response type as text while making http call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50798592/angular-6-how-to-set-response-type-as-text-while-making-http-call)