# im trying to get the data in backend by autogenerate web api

Tags: angular, rxjs, get, webapi

I'm trying to get my list with my autogenerated code in backend but it wont display in the front end.

[image: SERVER RESPONSE]

here's my code for getting the object

> .TS.SERVICES

```
getNextId(){
 return this.http.get(this.appSettings.baseURL +'Delivery/getNextSequence');
```

> .TS COMPONENT

```
getNextDRId(){
   this.microSvc.getNextId().subscribe((response: string) =>{
   this.idObj = response;
 })
}
```

> .HTML

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width" >
         <mat-label>Transaction #</mat-label>
         <input matInput type="text" formControlName="transactionType" readonly 
         ngModel{{idObj}} >
</mat-form-field>
```

[image]

Comment: Is the backed sending you a json response? what's the output if you console.log response; inside getNextDRId?, if the response from the server 200?

Comment: No output display when I put console.log

Comment: When doing the api call, in the inspect element - network of the browser, what are you recieving? is that call resturning a Status Code: 200 response? or maybe having a CORS error, maybe trying to log the error inside the subscribe could help you see if there's any error from the api response. If you make a screenshot of the header could be useful

Comment: I've already update my post and put the server response image

Comment: Thanks! the normal http response will expect the content-type to be something like `content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8`. If your going to receive another kind of response like text you might need to add a header to the api call in this post there are multiple examples of changing the api response <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50798592/angular-6-how-to-set-response-type-as-text-while-making-http-call>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245840/discussion-between-ryuuu-and-florencia-cames).

Comment: @FlorenciaCames Do you have any recommendation when you click the selection option dropdown it can be search cause now im using ngx-select-dropdown but it won't send to the databases

Comment: I left you some comments in the discussion chat

Comment: i send some picture i think mat-menu is not applicable for that @FlorenciaCames

Comment: I removed the linq tag because it's not related to the code in the question.